# List files in sub directories

Tags: find

I have a directory structure like below

/directory1/directory2/test.txt.

Here I have multiple directories in directory1 level and multiple directories in directory2 levels and few files are present in some of directory2 levels.

Is there a command which will display what sub directories has a file under it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to list only those directories that have files in, the `-empty` test of `find` may be what you need:

```
find /directory1 -type d -not -empty
```